# Deploy unmanaged dependecy dll within a .NET control

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-c++, deployment

i've a c# wincontrol that depends on a bunch of c++ unmanaged dlls.

```
dotnetctrl.dll
 +
 +--myliba.dll
 +
 +--mylibb.dll
```

Is there a way to include these mylib[a|b].dll when deploying the dotnetctrl.dll? 
i.e. When in a project I add a reference to dotnetctrl, is there a way to make the mylib dlls available in the right path just like .NET assembly?

Comment: What do you mean by deploy?  ClickOnce?  A setup project?  Library reference?  Copy/Paste?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the unmanaged DLLs, then in Properties, change the "Build Action" to "None" and the Copy to Output Directory to "Copy if newer"

Comment: hopefully, I am answering your question correctly.  This will, upon building your project, automatically copy those files (wherever they are) into the same folder as your .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the DLLs to the directory where the .NET binary file is and it will load the unmanaged DLL's within that directory.

Hope this helps.